# Get x509 policies in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, bouncycastle, x509certificate, x509

I can't extract the policy from an x509 certificate. The error that appears is: Exception in thread "main".

I am using BouncyCastle but i don't have much knowledge about it.

```
public class X509Reader {
    private static ASN1InputStream asn1InputStream;


    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("certificate.pem");
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

            while(bis.available() > 0){

                Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
                X509Certificate x = (X509Certificate) cert;


                byte[] policyBytes = x.getExtensionValue("2.5.29.33");
                asn1InputStream = new ASN1InputStream(policyBytes);
                Object policy = asn1InputStream.readObject();           


                System.out.println("Policy:" + policy);
                System.out.println("\n");
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

What should I do to fix it?

EDIT:

The stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.(ByteArrayInputStream.java:106)    at
>   org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1InputStream.(Unknown Source)  at
>   parser.X509Reader.main(X509Reader.java:48)

Comment: Please add the actual stacktrace produced by the code to the question.

Comment: Yes, I just added, thank you.

Comment: NullPointerException, so policyBytes is null.

Comment: Yes, actually I was putting the wrong OID, the right one is ("2.5.29.32"), however it came encoded, so I had to use ASN1OctetString and ASN1InputStream to decode. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to extract policies from a certificate using recent *BouncyCastle*:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1ObjectIdentifier;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.CertificatePolicies;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.PolicyInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509ExtensionUtils;

...

X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(bis);
byte[] extensionValue = certificate.getExtensionValue(
    Extension.certificatePolicies.getId()
);
CertificatePolicies policies = CertificatePolicies.getInstance(
    JcaX509ExtensionUtils.parseExtensionValue(extensionValue)
);
Set<ASN1ObjectIdentifier> policyIds = Arrays.stream(policies.getPolicyInformation())
        .map(PolicyInformation::getPolicyIdentifier)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```